# HTML formatted alert emails using monit

Tags: monitoring, monit

Is it possible to send HTML formatted alert emails using monit service ?

I would like to include coloured status based on the alert.

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/1/monit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. The mail format is given by monit. Only content can be changed.

Long answer: Kind of... I had some different ideas on how to distribute messages based on their importance and was not able to find a solution that matched my needs (different message transfer for different priorities). So I came up with a drop-in-replacement for an SMTP server. This runs as a systemd-service on my machine and is able to act differently for each message (mostly . You can simple enhance it to do most likely everything you can manage to do with a bash env. ;) You'll [find it on github](https://github.com/boppy/nitmo.fakesmtp).

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you for the contribution!